# Protocol error trying to parse XML response in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am successfully making an API call that is a SOAP request with an account number in the body.  I connected using `Httpurlconnection` and I am reading those results using `BufferedReader`:

```
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {​​​​​ // success
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {​​​​​
    {​​​​​
        sb.append(inputLine).append("\n");
        String xml2String = sb.toString();
```

Then using `documentbuilderfactory` to build the doc to read into the parser:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDom = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(inputLine));
```

And then try to parse:

```
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(returnList.item(0).getTextContent())));
Document doc = parser.getDocument();
NodeList responsedata = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
```

NodeList returnList = xmlDom.getElementsByTagName("DATA");

```
// Get the DATA
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(returnList.item(0).getTextContent())));
Document doc = parser.getDocument();
NodeList responsedata = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
```

This is the error I get (which includes the output from the API request):

```
Exception,no protocol:
{​​​​​"d":"<DATA><BussFlds><FieldName>FirstName</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[TESTY]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>LastName</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[TESTER]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>TYPE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>DATE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>CUSTCODE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>PREMCODE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>ADDRESS</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>CITY</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>STATE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>ZIP</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>ZIP4</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>ACCTBALANCE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>PASTDUE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>PHONE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds></DATA>"}​​​​​
```

I suspect that it is that curly bracket data on the first row or missing header information but I am not sure if that is the issue or how to fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: 1. Don’t read your response into a string (and in general, don’t use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder many years ago).  Pass the response directly to DocumentBuilder:  `Document xmlDom = docBuilder.parse(con.getInputStream());`  2.  The response you are reading is not XML, it’s JSON.  The value of the `"d"` object attribute appears to be an XML document, but you will first need to extract that XML from the JSON.

Comment: I am now getting Exception,Premature end of file.  Am I already consuming this stream?
      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();     
      if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
         con.getInputStream()));
       String inputLine;
       StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer
         ();
       while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        { sb.append(inputLine).append("\n"); 
        xml2String = sb.toString();
        in.close();

Comment: Ok, I was able to parse the JSON out so that I am left with just the XML but I still get the no protocol error:
Exception,no protocol: <DATA><BussFlds><FieldName>FirstName</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[TESTY]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>LastName</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[TESTER]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable></BussFlds><BussFlds><FieldName>TYPE</FieldName><Value><![CDATA[]]></Value><DataType>String</DataType><Format></Format><Editable>True</Editable>

Comment: Stop calling `docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(inputLine))`.  That constructor treats the string as a URI, not as XML input.

Comment: I am using the output from parsing the json (which reduced the output to just XML):
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        jdata = json.getString("d");
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
      Document xmlDom = docBuilder.parse(jdata);

Comment: Look at the documentation for [the parse(String) method of DocumentBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.lang.String)).  What is the name of the String parameter for the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response:

```
{"d":"<DATA><BussFlds>…
```

is **not** XML.  You **cannot** read it with a DocumentBuilder.

That response is in a format known as [JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html).  You cannot use an XML parser to read it.

So, you will want to pass the response to a JSON parser, *not* an XML parser.

A JSON “object” is basically a dictionary (that is, a lookup table) with string keys.  Your response has exactly one entry, whose key is `"d"`.  So you first need to [parse the response as JSON](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/Json.html#createParser-java.io.InputStream-):

```
String xml;
try (JsonParser jsonParser = Json.createParser(con.getInputStream())) {
    xml = jsonParser.getObject().getString("d");
}
```

(There are other JSON parsing libraries available.  I chose the one that is part of Java EE for the above example.)

Notice that the code does *not* attempt to read `con.getInputStream()` as a string first.  There is no benefit to doing that.  The parser accepts an InputStream directly.  Which means there is no need to use InputStreamReader, or BufferedReader, or StringBuffer.

Now that you have XML content in the `xml` variable, you can parse it with DocumentBuilder:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDom = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Side note: You should *never* use StringBuffer.  Use StringBuilder instead.  StringBuffer is a 26-year-old class that was part of Java 1.0, and it is designed for multithreaded use, which is almost never needed, and which adds a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(inputLine))
```

You are using the stringbuffer. Replace it with your variable xml2String